# implement a different behavior if the user clicks the [X] button vs. chooses the "Exit" menu item

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize, formclosing

Is there a way in C# to implement a different behavior based on whether the user clicks the [X] button, or chooses the "Exit" menu item?

What I want to do is make it so that if they click the [X], it minimizes to a tray icon, but if they right-click the tray icon, it brings up a context menu with an "Exit" option. If they click that "Exit" option, the application should exit.

I tried checking "object sender" in my Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) method... but it always seems to indicate the event is being sent by my main class?

Comment: What if you checked the contents of `e`?

Comment: Specifically what member of e should I be checking?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `bool` member to your form. Set it to `true` right before your exit menu item click event calls `Close`. In `FormClosing`, check to see if that variable is set and handle the logic appropriately.